Undergraduate references on Sturm-Liouville Theory and Green's Functions
Does anybody know of any clear treatments of Sturm-Liouville theory and Greens functions suitable to accompany undergraduate courses on the subject material? Thanks.

If you are looking for a book that treats both subjects and is focused on computations and not on proofs, you can have a look at Applied Partial Differential Equations by Richard Haberman

Preferably the book would be proof-based still, but I appreciate the recommendation.

And I assume that Evans is too difficult for the students you have in mind?

The case of ODEs is nicely treated in the book of Wolfgang Walter: Ordinary differential equations, Springer GTM 182

Take a look at the classic text by E. C. Titchmarsh. It's based on Advanced Calculus and Complex Analysis, and is a rigorous, self-contained and insightful work by a pioneer in the field.

Also take a look at this: https://www.amazon.com/Sturm-Liouville-Applications-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1846289718/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2YJH9B6KCDT8X&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.6jl6-GvC53Sda0TjmrI3t0ngbZQ-MNEG_DE4G3kMoHTeNfcgmTEbHuqISpUfHfYhqvvBOAAhaiNZiS3n4WASpodCfkctwp6qq9JetaDZfUZAMxdGFlLcfK6QcyQOOlF0wmaRMWwwz5egt1o5ndICQYDmM4WuaqRohIAJ96YezrXTV_Mn1zLqjSQporIA4NQ6XPyWkLnhwDrCCwkxsb2bQSXM_HmeepkPtyqMkyAJTO0.qzp6I8d6jUp_E_etjd7TMZ3KCNmwMw4Vmqm78MifiF8&dib_tag=se&keywords=sturm-liouville+theory&qid=1720723387&sprefix=sturm-liouville+theory%2Caps%2C130&sr=8-1
